# Can Nginx duplicate TCP/UDP traffic?

Tags: nginx, tcp

Below is my nginx.conf file, I have two upstreams, http_upstream and tcp_upstream, I make duplicated HTTP traffic and send it to load-balancer2.example.com:80 by using post_action, now I am wondering if I could make duplicated TCP/UDP traffic by using something similar to post_action?

```
daemon on;
user  root;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
    upstream tcp_upstream {
        server server1.example.com:2000;
        server server2.example.com:2000;
        server server3.example.com:2000;

    }
    server {
        listen 2000;
        proxy_pass tcp_upstream;
    }
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    client_header_buffer_size   512k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4   512k;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    client_body_buffer_size 1000M;

    upstream http_upstream {
        server server1.example.com:8088;
        server server2.example.com:8088;
        server server3.example.com:8088;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://http_upstream/;
            post_action @post_action;
        }
        location @post_action {
            proxy_pass http://load-balancer2.example.com:80;
        }

    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```